# JavaScript Regex to match math expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with this regular expression:

`let j = numberArray.join("").match(/^([\d]*\.{1,}[\d]+|[\d]+)|([-+*/](?=\.|[\d]))|\.[\d]+|[\d]+/g);`

This is the criteria I need to match:

1. a number can't have multiple decimals. For example, only numbers such as `.123` or `1.123` are allowed, but not `...33` or `1.2.3.3`.
2. An operator cannot be followed by one or more additional operators. So, the user can't consecutively input a `+` followed by a `*`.

An example input and out here:

input: `..123+*/.4.3.5-+..3+123`

would yield the output: `.123/.435+.3+123`

I actually think I have the second criteria (about operators) all set, but I've been really struggling with the decimal points. I'm new to regular expressions and am trying my best to crack this one, but it's starting to get to me after a while now. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Leaving aside that `..123` should probably be treated as an error rather than parsed as `0.123` (same with `.4.3.5`), you have other problems. This is going to result in some weird ambiguities. For example, it's not at all clear why you pick `/` over `+` or `*` in the example you gave (in the sequence `+*/`) or why you ignore the `-` sign entirely. In ordinary math, `-+3` would be `-3`, not `+3`.

Comment: To simplify my previous comment: if certain inputs are "not allowed," such as `...3` or `+*`, why try to make sense of those inputs instead of rejecting them? It's *much* easier to reject these nonsensical inputs and then parse any acceptable inputs than it is to try to make sense of the nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic would probably be easier if you carried out those operations *separately* - first find numbers with multiple decimals, and fix them so they contain only the first decimal place, *then* find repeated operators, and replace them with the final operator:

```js
const clean = str => str
  // Match zero or more digits, followed by a decimal,
  // followed by more digit and decimal characters
  // For everything past the first decimal, replace decimals with the empty string
  .replace(
    /(\d*\.)([\d.]+)/g,
    (_, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.replace(/\./g, '')
  )
  // Match 2 or more operators, capture the last operator in a group
  // Replace with the last operator captured
  .replace(
    /([-+/*]){2,}/g,
    '$1'
  );
  
console.log(clean('..123+*/.4.3.5-+..3+123'));
```

Comment: ooh man, thank you so much! I was trying to do it all in one go, but breaking it down is obviously so much easier.